# Update hours value if greater than 12 JavaScript line doesn't make any sense

Tags: javascript

Hi I am looking at this javascript code and there is this line
hrs = hrs - 12;
it supposedly should rest hours but it doesn't make any sense to me
I removed it and the clock seemed to work fine. can you confirm if I am right ? thanks

```js
// The week days
const weekDays = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];

// The Clock Ticker
function clockTicker() {

    // Clock units
    var date = new Date();
    var day = date.getDay();
    var hrs = date.getHours();
    var mins = date.getMinutes();
    var secs = date.getSeconds();



    // Update hours value if greater than 12
    if (hrs > 12) {

        hrs = hrs - 12;

        document.querySelector('#clock .period').innerHTML = 'PM';
    }
    else {

        document.querySelector('#clock .period').innerHTML = 'AM';
    }



    // Pad the single digit units by 0
    hrs = hrs < 10 ? "0" + hrs : hrs;
    mins = mins < 10 ? "0" + mins : mins;
    secs = secs < 10 ? "0" + secs : secs;

    // Refresh the unit values
    document.querySelector('#clock .day').innerHTML = weekDays[day];
    document.querySelector('#clock .hours').innerHTML = hrs;
    document.querySelector('#clock .minutes').innerHTML = mins;
    document.querySelector('#clock .seconds').innerHTML = secs;

    // Refresh the clock every 1 second
    requestAnimationFrame(clockTicker);
}

// Start the clock
clockTicker();
```

```html
<div id="clock">
  <span class="day"></span>
  <span class="hours"></span>:<span class="minutes"></span>:<span class="seconds"></span>
  <span class="period"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: It's converting 24-hour time to 12-hour time so you don't end up with "13 PM". You still have an error though as 12pm will show as "12 AM"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Date.getHours` according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getHours, returns

> An integer number, between 0 and 23, representing the hour for the given date according to local time.

So if you want your clock to read in 12  hour format,  you have to subtract 12 for hours in the range of 13 to 23 inclusive. Technically you should also represent the hours value of 0 (i.e. midnight) as though it was a value of 12, for the purposes of display, accordingly.